# Java multiarray updating

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have String array like this one:

```
String[][][][][] map = new String[9][13][2][1][1];
```

and when I'm trying update one fild, like this:

```
map[0][0][1][0][1]  = "true";
```

every fild is updating to "true", this one:

```
map[0][1][1][0][1]
```

this one:

```
map[0][2][1][0][1]
```

why this is happening?

this is my code:

```
int UP          = 0;
int UP_RIGHT    = 1;
int RIGHT       = 2;
int DOWN_RIGHT  = 3;
int DOWN        = 4;
int DOWN_LEFT   = 5;
int LEFT        = 6;
int LEFT_UP     = 7;

String[][][][][] map = new String[9][13][2][1][1];

public PitchMoveHelper() {
    String[][] move = {
            {String.valueOf(UP), "false"},
            {String.valueOf(UP_RIGHT), "false"},
            {String.valueOf(RIGHT), "false"},
            {String.valueOf(DOWN_RIGHT), "false"},
            {String.valueOf(DOWN), "false"},
            {String.valueOf(DOWN_LEFT), "false"},
            {String.valueOf(LEFT), "false"},
            {String.valueOf(LEFT_UP), "false"}
        };

    String[][] used = {{"used", "false"}};

    for(int z = 0; z < 9; z++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < 13; x++) {
            map[z][x][0] = used;
            map[z][x][1] = move;
        }
    }

    //this.updateLeftBand();
    //this.updateRightBand();
    //this.updateTopBand();
    //this.updateBottomBand();

    map[0][0][1][0][1]  = "true"; 

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(getPitchMap()));
}
```

Comment: Aren't you getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: `map[0][0][1][0][1] = "true"` would first throw an index out of bounds exception... Which suggests that you might not be running the code you think you are running...

Comment: That you are not doing it right. Write a simple program with the four lines of code that you have put in the question and you will check that it is simply not true. With additional code we might help more.

Comment: check my edit, i don't get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: It's not possible. It should throw that exception. You are accessing the index `1` at the end, which is out of bounds, as the size in the last bracket is `1`.

Comment: Why don't you think about different data structure for your problem?  With too much of this, you will be totally confused with the indexes being used.

Comment: @muruga what do You suggest?

Comment: @DawidSajdak I would use a custom class containing all the required values as a single object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that the `String` array stores *references*, not actual strings.  When you say

```
map[z][x][0] = used;
map[z][x][1] = move;
```

There is a *single* instance of `used` being referenced by ALL elements `[z][x][0]` of `map` (and the same for `move` and `[z][x][1]`.  Any change indexed by the 4th of 5th subscript is changing that single instance, affecting what is seen by all subscripts.

To clarify more, all the following entries in `map` point to the same instance:

```
map[0][0][0]
map[0][1][0]
       .
       .
map[0][12][0]
map[1][0][0]
  etc.
```

To solve the problem you need to make a deep copy of `used` and `move` for every assignment in the loop:

```
for(int z = 0; z < 9; z++) {
    for(int x = 0; x < 13; x++) {
        map[z][x][0] = deepCopy(used);
        map[z][x][1] = deepCopy(move);
    }
}
```

Where `deepCopy()` makes a complete copy of the input array.

```
String[][] deepCopy(String [][] arr)
{
    String[][] temp = new String[arr.length][];
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
         temp[i] = new String[arr[i].length];
         for (int j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++)
             temp[i][j] = arr[i][j];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Java String is immutable, existing instances can not be changed.

Comment: @Jim Garrison thanks a lot for this answer, but I'm still don't know how should look deepCopy method, could You help me with this?

Comment: @DawidSajdak This solves your immediate issue, but the bigger question is your choice of data structure.  A 5-dimensional array will always be difficult to comprehend and debug.  You should try to think about the problem in terms of lists and possibly maps.

Answer (score 1):

The key thing you need to realize is that

```
int[][] example = new int[2][2];
example[1][0] = 1;
example[0] = example[1];
```

Does **NOT COPY** the second row to the first. But it makes it an **ALIAS** to the same memory - i.e. the row is *identical* to the first.

If you want to copy an array, element-per-element, use

```
System.arraycopy(...);
```

If you want to do copy an array-of-arrays, you need a deep copy.

The simplest thing for you is if you **copy every single entry**. This may be somewhat slower, but it is probably a concept you can easily use for now.

Again:

```
array2 = array1;
```

**DOES NOT COPY** array1 to array2. But it makes them **one array**.